# emulate ruby's index accessor, []

Tags: ruby, hash, syntactic-sugar

I understand how Ruby's syntactic sugar lets us assign a value to a variable like this

```
o = ExampleClass.new
o.name = "An object"
```

when `ExampleClass` has a method:

```
name=(new_name)
```

How does this work for a class like `Hash`? How would I name my method if I want to do this?

```
h = MyHash.new
h[:key] = value
```

I am not inheriting from the `Hash` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just have methods

```
def [](key_to_retrieve)
   #return corresponding value here
end
```

and

```
def []=(key_to_set, value_to_set)
   #set key/value here
end
```

Comment: @x-treme Please remember that you can "accept" this answer to reward the answerer and to let other users know in the future that this answer best solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

JacobM pretty much answered the question; but I would like to add something which I read a little back about **Mutable classes**.

You may find this interesting. You can define a mutable class quickly using `Struct` as:

```
MyHash = Struct.new(:x, :y)
#This creates a new class MyHash with two instance variables x & y
my_obj = MyHash.new(3, 4)
#=> #<struct MyHash x=3, y=4>
my_obj[:x] = 10
#=> #<struct MyHash x=10, y=4>
my_obj.y = 11
#=> #<struct MyHash x=10, y=11>
```

This automatically makes the instance variables *readable*, *writable* and *mutable* by `[]=`

You can always open the class to add some new stuff;

```
class MyHash
  def my_method
    #do stuff
  end
  def to_s
    "MyHash(#{x}, #{y})"
  end
end
```